# PHP how to detect chrome on IOS, Android, and Windows?

Tags: php, android, ios, google-chrome

eregi is an older code and works when I load chrome for chrome specific functions.  I have seen Java tutorials on detection for iOS, Android, and windows, but for PHP it seems limited.

`preg_match` seemed to give me issues on how this was used. How would you detect it on all 3 so you get the correct browser?

This is what I currently use:

```
function is_chrome()
{
return(eregi("chrome", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']));
//return(preg_match(“/applewebkit/i”, $_SERVER[‘HTTP_USER_AGENT’]));
}

if(is_chrome())
{
    // code for Chrome Browser here

    echo $chrome = 'You are using Google Chrome Browser.';

 } else{
    echo $chrome = 'hide';

}
```

Comment: ereg is deprecated and REMOVE from newer phps. you shouldn't be using the ereg functions, period. and why are you reinventing the wheel for browser detection? there's plenty of libraries one single trivial google query away for you to use.

Comment: You have fancy quotes, not normal double quotes, around the `preg` pattern. If you're only checking for the presence of a fixed string, you only need `stripos`

Comment: Could you show me an example of stripos being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use some 3rd party library to detect browsers, e.g. [Browser.php](https://github.com/cbschuld/Browser.php)

Typical Usage:

```
$browser = new Browser();
if( $browser->getBrowser() == Browser::BROWSER_CHROME && $browser->getPlatform() == Browser::PLATFORM_WINDOWS ) {
    echo 'Chrome on Windows';
}
```

Comment: I will give this a look!